# how to get the start date of the day from specific time stamp in java

Tags: java, time

sample:

```
Long timeStamp = 1466058808;
Time time = new Time(timeStamp );
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(time));
```

print is: 2016-05-31 08:19:07

How can I get expected results is : 2016-05-31 00:00:00

Thanks!

And finally get the time stamp of 2016-05-31 00:00:00  This is what i want

So anyone know how to make it?

Comment: What is `Time` class?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html

Answer (score 7):

Simple, use:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
```

Or if you want a long (and have java 8):

```
LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1466058808, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Comment: Yes,It works.Thanks
And finally get the time stamp of 2016-05-31 00:00:00 This is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The [Answer by krzyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37852113/642706) is close but ignores the crucial issue of time zone. Let's try that again using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 ([ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)) and further adapted to Android ([ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)).

### Count of seconds from epoch

You do not say so in the Question, but we assume the `Long` of `1466058808` is a number of whole seconds from the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

### `Instant`

First we convert that to an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1466058808L );
```

### Time Zone

Determining a date, and the start of the day, depends on a time zone. For any given moment, the date can vary around the world by time zone. A few moments after midnight in Paris is still “yesterday” in Montréal.

### `ZonedDateTime`

You can make wide use of `Instant` in your code. Generally best practice is to perform business logic, data storage, logging, and so on in UTC. Apply a time zone only where required such as display to a user. Apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

### Using `LocalDate` for start-of-day

To get the start of the day we need to go through the `LocalDate` class. Note that we should always pass the optional time zone argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. That default can change at any time, even *during* runtime, as any code in any app of the JVM can make a call to [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-). Better to be specific.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

Note that you should *not* assume the day starts at `00:00:00.0`. [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) may mean the day starts at a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time).

### One-liner

I do not recommend doing so, but you can combine all this into a single line.

```
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1466058808L ) , ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

use a Calendar, so you can extract date properties:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);

//getting the desired properties
cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```